# How to change the url of angular custom element

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I want to change the url of custom element in angular project i.e currently the project is running with custom element successfully using url http://localhost:4200/#/wb/(some-id). My need is to change the url to http://localhost:4200/project without changing the routing configuration of components. How this can be done?

index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Workbench</title><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
</head>
<body>


      <app-root></app-root>
      <work-bench></work-bench>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="./workbench.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></link>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to change routes without changing route configuration ?

Comment: I meant without changing the route configuration of angular component which I have  made custom element

Comment: what do you mean by custom element?

Comment: Angular elements